# Raising the hypertarget of chapter labels

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref, etoolbox, varioref

When using `twocolumn` mode, it is a known issue that references to chapter headings point to the baseline rather than the chapter heading.

In a previous question, I asked how to fix this for the table of contents, but I realize that the solution does not solve the same issue for `\ref` and friends.

My attempt tried to patch `\label` in the same way as `\addcontentsline`, but this makes no difference to the `\hypertarget` of `\*ref`. How can I modify the target of `chapter:` labels? If it helps, bookmarks referencing the chapter are always prefixed by `chapter:`.

Reprex:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[twocolumn]{geometry}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Add extra hyper target for chapter: chapter..\thechapter
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \mbox{\raisebox{25pt}[0pt][0pt]{\hypertarget{.\theHchapter}{}}% Add 
    \chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\hspace{1em}}%
}

\makeatletter
% Update \addcontentsline to jump to new hyper target _only_ if \chapter is used
\patchcmd{\addcontentsline}% <cmd>
  {\Hy@writebookmark}% <search>
  {\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{chapter}{#2}=0 % Chapter mark
     \edef\@currentHref{.\theHchapter}%
   \fi
   \Hy@writebookmark}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

\patchcmd{\label}% <cmd>
  {\Hy@writebookmark}% <search>
  {\edef\@currentHref{.\theHchapter}%
   \Hy@writebookmark}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

\makeatother


\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{A}
\chapter{foo\label{chapter:foo}}
\chapter{bar}
\part{B}
\chapter{Baz}\label{chapter:Baz}
\chapter{Foobar}

\Vref{chapter:Baz}.

\Vref{chapter:foo}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hyperref automatically provides targets at the top of each page by the name `page.\thepage`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[twocolumn]{geometry}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcommand{\topref}[1]% #1 = label
{\hyperlink{page.\getpagerefnumber{#1}}{\getrefnumber{#1}}}

\begin{document}

chapter \topref{chapter:foo}

\part{A}
\chapter{foo}\label{chapter:foo}
\chapter{bar}
\part{B}
\chapter{Baz}\label{chapter:Baz}
\chapter{Foobar}

\end{document}
```